# Function crash in viewController

Tags: swift, adobe

Hi developers I have this issue with Adobe Audience Manager POD

in my VC I have this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureUI()
        ACPAudience.signal(withData: ["ViewedScreen": "ButtonClicked"]) { (response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            } else {
                print(response as Any)
            }
        }
    }
```

every time I run it it crash with this:

*dynamic_cast error 2: One or more of the following type_info's has hidden visibility or is defined in more than one translation unit. They should all have public visibility. N20AdobeMarketingMobile6ModuleE, N20AdobeMarketingMobile13ConfigurationE, N20AdobeMarketingMobile22ModuleDetailsInterfaceE.*

implementation is correct as far I know
[image]

[image]

the solution is creating a **NSNotification** in the app delegate works no crashes or anything weird

code in app delegate is pretty much the same

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        

        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(getProfileACP2), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "getProfileACP"), object: nil)
}

@objc private func getProfileACP2(){
        ACPAudience.signal(withData: ["ViewedScreen": "ButtonClicked"]) { (response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            } else {
                print(response as Any)
            }
        }
        
    }
```

then on the VC works like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("getProfileACP")
    print("----------------------------------------------")
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "getProfileACP"), object: nil)
    print("----------------------------------------------")
    print("getProfileACP")
}
```

after calling it seems like it takes some time after giving the response is not immediately
[image]

Comment: Does it really crash? It doesn't seem so, it look like your app is continuing, not crashing, just getting an error.

Comment: @Larme thank you for responding, indeed is crashing

Comment: What’s the last lines of your console output?